# Cannot use my Java classes working with Jasper Reports: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have installed JasperReports Studio 6.17 in order to generate reports with Jasper Reports. Everything is ok, i can define my templates (jrxml files), filled them with jdbc or cvs remote data, and export them correctly to several formats.

The problem is when i try to use one my own Java classes such as Scritplett or as functions expressions. There is no way to recognize my classes. ClassNotFoundException is thrown each time.

Build path seems to be ok. All depedencies seems to be correct also, but i am not able to extend the functionality interacting with my Java classes. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

pd: I am not generating reports on the fly, just from the template, declaratively.

[image]

Comment: You can try to add your class(es) or jar with help of `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` -> `"Add .."`

Comment: @AlexK src folder is on the path. Also i tried to export my classes in an external jar and then import them and no way. Same exception is thrown.

Comment: Did you restart JSS after adding the jar file?

Comment: How are you running the `jasper` file? You say that `you're not generating reports on the fly` what exactly are you doing to run it?  Command line? Web API? Etc?

Comment: @AlexK Yes I did.

Comment: @kendavidson In the Report Desing perspective, just opening the jrxml file and clicking on the preview tab.

Comment: @ValMartinez Looks like a JSS bug

Comment: @ValMartinez BTW, Are you sure that you are using the fully qualified name of class?

Comment: @AlexK Yes Alex. Its canonical name: package.name. I agree. Seems a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking to the Jasper Community, they have given me a solution.

Its a bug in the 6.17 version. In order to solved it, just add an extra jar to the plugin installation folder, relaunch Jasper with -clean option and done. Now I can refer and use my own classes within the report.

Details here: https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/13616#comment-873711

Also told me that a new release is comming and will fix this issue.