# How to create a QR Code in JasperSoft Studio?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to create a QR code in JasperSoft Studio.

We have a report properly working on production containing a QR code. But after a new installation of JasperSoft Studio, we are unable to run the report.

While compiling the report we are getting the error:

> com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type

Details :

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
    1. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                    value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage( //$JR_EXPR_ID=38$
                            <---------------------------------------------->
    2. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                    value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage( //$JR_EXPR_ID=38$
                            <---------------------------------------------->
    3. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                    value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage( //$JR_EXPR_ID=38$
                            <---------------------------------------------->
    3 errors
    .

        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:229)

        at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:289)

        at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:141)

        at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportsBuilder.compileJRXML(JasperReportsBuilder.java:212)

        at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction.actionCompile(CompileAction.java:154)

        at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction$1.run(CompileAction.java:98)

        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

We have setup the Java Build Path and added Core and JavaSE jars but the report doesn't compile.

[image]

[image]

The QR code is inserted in the report using the following expression :

```
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
    new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
        $F{QRCODE},
        com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400
    )
)
```

[image]

How can I solve that?

### Related questions

The most similar question in Stack Overflow is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853682/print-a-qr-code-in-jasperreports-5-6-1), but there no answer could be provided.

Comment: Did you try to simpify the expression and write it using only one line?

Comment: Yes I did @AlexK. But it didn't work. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What version of JSS (Studio) are you using? Looks like a bug of IDE. You can also looks at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69699763/876298) post

Comment: @AlexK I'm on TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.17.0. Will look at your link. Thanks

Comment: @AlexK Thank you very much for your comment ! I had the version that has the bug. Installed the version 6.20 and everything works properly.